# Start AVD from jenkins

Tags: android, python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am try to launch an android emulator from jenkins.
I have written a batch file as follows:

```
cd E:\android-sdk\tools
emulator.exe -avd "AVD" -wipe-data
```

I execute this batch file from jenkins. But it does not launch the emulator.

I have also tried launching it from python as follows:

```
bash = "E:\\android-sdk\\tools\\emulator"
print "executing: " + bash

f_handle = open('test_output_launch.txt','w+')
process = subprocess.Popen([bash, '-avd', 'AVD'])
```

But the latter gives an error `'PANIC: Could not open: AVD'`.
Where as when I run the batch file normally without jenkins, everything works perfectly.
I need to launch the AVD, install apk on it, and run some automated tests via jenkins. Please help!!

Comment: where did you keep the python script?

Comment: The python script is executed through the batch file.

Comment: Are you using Master-Slave setup? If yes, what are the OS on both Master & Slave?

Comment: Hi TechNext, its not a master-slave setup. I am running it on a virtual machine, which is located on a remote proxmox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked with 'Android Emulator Plugin' of jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be permission issue. Try running the jenkins client as admin.

For Python, change your subprocess call to

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['emulator.exe', '-avd', 'AVD'], cwd=bash)
```

Comment: I tried the change in subprocess call. It still gives the same error : 'PANIC: Could not open: AVD' when run through jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can try your script in command line first.